# How do I get the characters inbetween two characters within a string in PHP

Tags: php, string, variables

I have an file. Each value looks like this:

```
Peter | Stuart | 10293 | 13/02/93 | email@domain.com | [data6] | [data7] | [data8]
```

My question is,  I want data 6, 7 and 8 to be in seperate variables.

So the variable would be like this (in PHP code)

```
$data6 = [data6]
$data7 = [data7]
$data8 = [data8]
```

Does that make sense?  I understand a loop will be involved,  it is more getting the data in between the "|" symbol I am not 100% sure about.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use explode:

```
$data_array = explode("|",$your_string);
```

then you can access those values like any other array:

```
$data_array[5]; // this would be data 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Use PHP [explode](http://php.net/explode). In this case you would iterate to each line and split the string by the pipe `|` and refer to the values you need by their keys e.g. `data[6]` would be in index 5 of the array generated by `explode` like `$data[5]`.